# How to update the Flutter SDK?

Tags: flutter

I'm new in Flutter. 2 months ago I have installed flutter SDK in windows. 
Now I have seen a lot of updates available.

I want to update "Flutter SDK".

How to update Flutter SDK to the latest version?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I want to upgrade most latest version. So I used below commands:

```
flutter channel dev
```

Flutter has 4 project branches / channels ie stable, master, dev, beta. First when we install it. flutter install stable channel.

If you want to switch :

```
flutter channel chanel_name
```

Then update that :

```
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: 'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: you didn't installed flutter. this answer is for update flutter not new installation.

Comment: Dude if I didn't install it so what did I wanted to upgrade? :D
It is installed and I'm coding on it.

Comment: check variable path.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path

Comment: Caution -> do not use the command on a patchy network. Once the command is run, some important flutter sdk version related files are deleted before the download. So it has to complete the download in order to be usable again

Answer (score 126):

You can write

```
flutter upgrade
```

command in terminal to update flutter sdk

Comment: Thanks for your answer. flutter upgrade update but not latest version. Latest version is 0.7.5 (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/releases) but after flutter upgrade, it update to 0.6.0 not 0.7.5.

Comment: May be you are in beta channel. You can check using flutter channel command. If you want to change channel the use flutter channel dev after that use flutter upgrade command to upgrade to latest version.

Comment: Will this upgrade to the stable version or the dev version by default?

Comment: No, it will only update to the latest version of whatever channel you are using.

Comment: 'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: May be you didn't set your sdk path correctly. @Taba

Comment: well actually I was updating it using the "flutter upgrade" Button in `pubspec.yaml` file in android studio before, but after `android studio version 3.6.3` the button disappeared. and now when I try to run `flutter upgrade` in cmd even when I change the directory to flutter sdk yet I get the above error. Where should I place the SDK?

Comment: You need to set flutter SDK path using like bellow 
 export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin"
@Taba

Answer (score 15):

Open your terminal and type

```
flutter upgrade --force
```

Comment: This worked for me when "flutter upgrade" didn't. What does --force do?

Comment: `--force` overwrites local changes to your Flutter installation. As per the CLI: "Your flutter checkout has local changes that would be erased by upgrading. If you want to keep these
changes, it is recommended that you stash them via "git stash" or else commit the changes to a local
branch. If it is okay to remove local changes, then re-run this command with --force."

Answer (score 15):

**Using Tool Menu:**

You can update in android studio using Tools so follow these steps
Android Studio -> Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Upgrade.

[image]

**Using Command:**

You can write a command in the terminal to update flutter SDK

```
flutter upgrade
```

Or if you have to upgrade it any way you can use

```
flutter upgrade --force
```

Answer (score 9):

Sometime `flutter upgrade` seems not responsive but actually it's doing something. Just add the `-v` or `--verbose` option to see what actually happening.

```
flutter upgrade --verbose
```

Answer (score 8):

We can upgrade the flutter by simply using Flutter command forcefully.

Like this one :

```
flutter upgrade --force
```

But before that we will have to make sure & take a note of few things otherwise it can be risky & we might loss some of our work as well.

**Important Note :**

- While upgrading the flutter make sure all of your local work is already pushed to the server & you do have a proper back up of all of your code
- Make sure you do have a back of all live changes you did & with working condition

Hopefully this will help out everyone.

Answer (score 3):

A very much simple way is to go and download the new SDK and extract the the folder. Then replace the old sdk folder with the new one

Answer (score 1):

Just run the `flutter upgrade` in terminal.

Or if you have to upgrade it any way you can use `flutter upgrade --force`

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio , in toolbar at top of the screen go to Android Studio -> Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Upgrade.[[image: Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Upgrade.]

Or open terminal and type command: flutter upgrade and hit Enter.