# Get Dart Devtools to open in Chrome

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Currently, Dart Devtools opens as a tab in VSCode. I want it to go back to opening in Chrome as it did in previous versions of Flutter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update VSCode to the newest Version.

[VSCode Update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60807680/11921453)

Update Flutter

[flutter Update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52135286/11921453)

Now run your Project and then click [ctrl] + [alt] + [d] for running dart devtools. VSCode is asking you where you wish to open DevTools.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I also found that clicking on the `Dart DevTools` option on the status bar also gives you the same options

Answer (score 6):

Do not bother about it mate, just add this line on **settings.json**

```
 "dart.embedDevTools": false
```

Then you will get again DevTools on Chrome. Just shortcode: Ctrl + Alt + D.

That's it.

Comment: not working for me

Comment: Double check your json's structure from settings.json file because installing several extensions may damage the structure itself and vsCode just warn you and sadly do not fix it for you.

Answer (score 5):

```
"dart.embedDevTools": false
```

is not relevant anymore, instead you should use:

```
"dart.devToolsLocation": "external"
```

Answer (score 3):

In your terminal, run:

```
dart devtools
```

It will open Flutter Devtools page in your default browser. When you start an application is should print an id starting and ending with **ws**. This id will be used to connect devtools to the app