# how can I upgrade My flutter Documentation to 3.0.3

Tags: flutter, documentation, upgrade

I'm New to flutter and have flutter 3.0.2 and I want to know how I can upgrade it to 3.0.3.
thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update the Flutter SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52135231/how-to-update-the-flutter-sdk)

Comment: I guess 'flutter upgrade' in terminal/cmd should be an answer for him